# Django - user uploaded images not appearing in media/images folder

Tags: python, django

When I complete the profile of a test user, it adds the name of the uploaded file to the DB, and I am able to access the user's profile image file name with `{{ user.profile.profile_pic }}`, however the image does not appear in my_project/media/images. Thanks for any advice.

Here are the relevant files, I can add more if needed:

**settings.py** (last two lines)

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False, is_active=True, is_confirmed=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address.")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users mush have a password.")
        user_obj = self.model(email = self.normalize_email(email))
        user_obj.set_password(password) #also to change password
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_superuser
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.confirmed = is_confirmed
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password, is_staff=True)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_confirmed(self):
        #confirmed email address
        return self.confirmed



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #extend extra data, i.e. name, location, ect.
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=16)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
def complete_setup(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #handle form data
        #and redirect to home or whatever they were looking at
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        user.profile.first_name = request.POST["first_name"]
        user.profile.profile_pic = request.POST["image"]
        user.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        #serve form
        #only serve if profile not complete
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print("user is logged in...")
            try:
                name = request.user.profile.name
                print("user has completed profile")
                return render(request, 'home')
            except:
                return render(request, 'accounts/complete-setup.html')
        else:
            print("user is not logged in")
            return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `user.profile.profile_pic = request.POST["image"]` use this

```
`user.profile.profile_pic = request.FILES["image"]`
```

also, hope yo have add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

add this in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # urls
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had urls.py correctly but I needed request.FILES and enctype in my form.